# Custom meta tag name color in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new in developement. I'm using VSCode with One Dark+ theme. I would like to change a meta tag name color from "#E06C75" to "#1b1ff0". I tried modified the settings.json but it didn't work. Please help me to resolve this issue.

To make it clear what is "meta tag name" (maybe I use wrong words), it means something like `<xs:complexType> </xs:complexType>` in XML file or html tag like `<p>`, `<br>` etc...

Here is my settings.json file. 
Hope it helps.

Thank you.

```
    {
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations":{
        "tokenColors": [
           {
            "scope": "entity.name.tag",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#1b1ff0"
            }
           },
           {
            "scope": "text.html.laravel-blade source.php.embedded.line.html entity.name.tag.laravel-blade",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#1b1ff0"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is just a little off:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {            // this is different
    "textMateRules": [                          // this is different
       {
        "scope": "entity.name.tag",  
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#1b1ff0"
        }
       },
       {
        "scope": "text.html.laravel-blade source.php.embedded.line.html entity.name.tag.laravel-blade",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#1b1ff0"
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply.  Unfortunately, when I copied your code into settings.json, I had a notification said that "Unknown Configuration Setting".

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension to configure the tokens colors. Althought I don't know if this plugin provides a way to says "any token", but since is using Regex I think there is and you should figure it out (maybe something like `<*>*<*>`, not actual Regex code btw but you get the idea)